# Unable to access database while testing with firebase-functions-test

Tags: firebase, testing, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test using firebase-functions-test. I'm wondering if I've done something wrong in the setup, because I've noticed that my function stops after trying to access the database.

```
const config = {
    databaseURL: '******,
    projectId: '*****'
};

const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(config, './devKey.json');

const myFunctions = require('../index.js');

const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.search.fetchProfiles);

let before = test.database.makeDataSnapshot('', 'cloud-functions/fetchProfiles/
-L8eDyqVjH2WcsnfFDj3/request');
let after = test.database.makeDataSnapshot({
    version: '1.0.8', 
    userIds: ['-L4dcm7BSctgsqAzpeOP']
    }, 'cloud-functions/fetchProfiles/-L8eDyqVjH2WcsnfFDj3/request' );

let change = test.makeChange(before, after);

let context = {
    params: {userId: '-L8eDyqVjH2WcsnfFDj3'}
};

wrapped(change, context);
```

Then, when this line of code is ran within the function:

```
data.after.ref.parent.child('state').once('value')
```

It is not successful. The function has no problems when deployed. In particular, are my data snapshots created properly?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [version 0.1.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/releases/tag/v0.1.1) of firebase-functions-test.

Comment: Thanks, but I updated that and still have the same issue. I updated the question to make my problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but it's 3 weeks later now and I tried it, and now it works. I don't recall changing anything.